# Boost-log linker error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, linker, boost-log

i've downloaded and builded Boost 1.55 from source. I'm trying to use Boost-log. In basic case (http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html)/log/tutorial.html#log.tutorial.trivial it's working fine without any problems, but when i try to use some more advanced features(like this - http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/example/doc/tutorial_fmt_stream.cpp ) i'm getting this error:

> main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl
>   boost::filesystem::path_traits::convert(char const *,char const
>   *,class std::basic_string,class std::allocator>
>   &,class std::codecvt const &)" (?convert@path_traits@filesystem@boost@@YAXPBD0AAV?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@ABV?$codecvt@GDH@5@@Z)
>   referenced in function "void __cdecl
>   boost::filesystem::path_traits::dispatch,class std::allocator > >(class
>   std::basic_string,class
>   std::allocator > const &,class std::basic_string,class
>   std::allocator > &,class std::codecvt const &)"
>   (??$dispatch@V?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@@path_traits@filesystem@boost@@YAXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@AAV?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@4@ABV?$codecvt@GDH@4@@Z)
>
> 1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl
>   boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::aux::code_convert(unsigned short const
>   *,unsigned int,class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > &,class
>   std::locale const &)"
>   (?code_convert@aux@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@YAXPBGIAAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABVlocale@6@@Z)
>   referenced in function "private: void __thiscall
>   boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::basic_formatting_ostream,class std::allocator>
>   ::aligned_write(unsigned short const *,__int64)" (??$aligned_write@G@?$basic_formatting_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@AAEXPBG_J@Z)
>
> 1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static
>   class std::codecvt const & __cdecl
>   boost::filesystem::path::codecvt(void)"
>   (?codecvt@path@filesystem@boost@@SAABV?$codecvt@GDH@std@@XZ)
>   referenced in function "public: __thiscall
>   boost::filesystem::path::path(char const (&)[14],void
>   *)" (??$?0$$BY0O@$$CBD@path@filesystem@boost@@QAE@AAY0O@$$CBDPAX@Z)

So basically it can't find functions convert(...), code_convert(...) and codecvt(...) in .lib files.

I've already tried to add all release libraries (.lib files made while building boost) to "additional libraries" and generally i think that visual studio find all libraries, but can't find those functions in libraries. Any ideas how can i fix this?

I've build Boost 1.55 from source using visual studio 2010 (msvc10.0), 32 bit, release and debug. I'm working on windows 7 x64.

Comment: MSVC auto-links boost libs, so you don't have to link them explicitly. However `unsigned short` looks suspicious. Check that you compile everything with "/Zc:wchar_t" option, i.e. "wchar_t Is Native Type".

Comment: are you using the same settings (read: `#defines`) for boost.log in your project that were used when compiling the sources? In our case we had to make sure to use `BOOST_LOG_NO_THREADS` in projects including boost.log headers, otherwise we'd get different though equally annoying linker errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and I could fix it by changing one of the Project properties on VisualStudio 2010.

Go to:

**Property Pages -> ConfigurationProperties -> C/C++ -> Language -> Treat WChar_t As Built in Type:**

And set the property to:

**Yes (/Zc:wchar_t)**

I hope it will be helpful for you too :)

Take care,